# jQuery addClass method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

When I call the jQuery method .addClass() do I need to check if the class already exists or it's already implemented? I mean, if I call the same method twice, like

```
$(var).addClass('class1');
$(var).addClass('class1');
```

does it cause any issue or it's fine? Thanks

Comment: It's absolutely fine. jQuery is very tolerant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need to. addClass internally checks whether class exists. if not, then adds the class

**[Reference](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/classes.js#L38-L40)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

For check if an element have your class name, you can do:

```
$(var).hasClass('class1');
```